# How to get firebase server time?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Tried this code:

```
this.db.object('data/account/temp').set({date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
    var time = firebase.database().ref('data/account/temp').once('value', function(snap){return snap.val().date});
    this.added = time + 5000000;
    //do other things with "this.added"
```

How to return data to the variable so i can do other thing with that?

It works with this code **but**:

```
firebase.database().ref('data/account/temp').once('value', function(snap){console.log(snap.val().date}));
```

**But** i need it in a variable to work with.

Comment: You have the value as a variable within the callback function (you called it `snap`). Within that function you can either apply it to another variable in an outer scope or call another function with that variable as parameter.

Comment: That will be a mess if i call it within that snapped function. yes outer scope is possible since console logging works within the function. If i add `firebase.database().ref('data/account/temp').once('value', function(snap){this.fTime = snap.val().date})); let finaltime = this.fTime + 500;` won't work. maybe i have to change this coding structure

Comment: `firebase.database().ref('data/account').once('value', function(snap){
 console.log(snap.child('temp').val().date);
 });` and now i can work with parent node and its child